# Kafka python graceful shutdown of consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-3.7, kafka-python

I am trying to gracefully shutdown a kafka consumer, but the script blocks with Stopping HeartBeat thread.
How can i gracefully close the consumer on a SIGTERM with kafka-python.
This is what i have done

```
import logger as logging
import time
import sys
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import numpy as np
import signal


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Cons:
    def __init__(self):

        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sigterm_handler)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.sigterm_handler)
        self.consumer = KafkaConsumer('dummy-topic', group_id='poll-test', bootstrap_servers=['b1'])

    def sigterm_handler(self, signum, frame):
        log.info("Sigterm handler")
        self.consumer.close(autocommit=False)
        sys.exit(0)



    def consume(self):
        try:
            while True:
                records = self.consumer.poll(timeout_ms=500, max_records=500)
                for topic_partition, consumer_records in records.items():
                    for record in consumer_records:
                        log.info("Got Record - {}".format(record))
                    #code to manually commit


        except ValueError as e:
            log.exception("exception")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c=Cons()
    c.consume()
```

With debug logs enabled, this is the output i get and the code gets blocked on this.

```
^C2020-04-28 07:18:33,050 - MainThread - __main__ - INFO - Sigterm handler
2020-04-28 07:18:33,050 - MainThread - kafka.consumer.group - DEBUG - Closing the KafkaConsumer.
2020-04-28 07:18:33,051 - MainThread - kafka.coordinator - INFO - Stopping heartbeat thread
```

What is the reason behind this? and what is right way to close a consumer on SIGTERM or SIGINT?

Comment: You might need to update "controlled.shutdown.enable=true" in the config/server.properties file.

Comment: But isnt that for the broker? this is the consumer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this ultimately got fixed in 2020, so any recent version should be OK:

https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/commit/91daea329bb40ed80bddef4635770d24b670b0c6